# sort based on templatefield gridview asp.net web forms 4.5

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I'm trying to sort a gridview based on templatefields.
My gridview basically has a few databoundfields, and in the backend
I call rowdatabound function to get data from other tables.

Some thing like this..

```
<asp:Gridview runat="server" ID="testGrid" selectMethod="testGrid_GetData"
 AutoGenerateColumns="false" AutoGenerateDeleteButton="true" OnRowDataBound="testGrid_RowDataBound" ItemType="testItem"
 DeleteMethod="testGrid_DeleteItem" AutoGenerateEditButton="true" UpdateMethod="testGrid_UpdateItem" DataKeyNames="idx">
    <Columns>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Field1" HeaderText="Field1" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Field2" HeaderText="Field2" />
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Field3"></asp:TemplateField>
    </Columns>
<asp:GridView>
```

And I'm calling from GetData from Backend and also rowDataBound to get data from other table, 
something like this..

```
public Iqueryable testGrid_GetData() {
    var testIt = db.testItems.orderbyDescending(r => r.Field1);
    return testIt;
}

protected void testGrid_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e) 
{
    string f1 = e.Row.Cells[1].Text.ToString();
    var item = db.otherItems.Where(it => it.FieldFrom1.Equals(f1)).field3;
    e.Row.Cells[4].Text = field3;

}
```

This may be an oversimplification of what I'm doing right now but I think I can solve my problem if someone could sort from here.

So my goal is to sort by Field3, and I did not used any datatables or datasources and all the tutorials are asking me to do so.

I've even tried using OnSorting function but I have no clue where to start.
Also worried that even though I fired Onsorting function, the RowdataBound event will override that function.

If someone could help me with this, it would be truly grateful.

And again, the code is much, much more complicated than this and all other functionalities beside this is working fine, so it would be nice if I could do this without changing the structure of the code too much.

Thanks in advance!!